# php Daylight off for 2 weeks after change

Tags: php, dst

I have been ask by my company to fix a daylight savings time issue on our web site. The problem is after a change to or from daylight savings time it does not show up via the site for a couple weeks. The OS changes correctly, and shows correctly. The web site uses the function below to signal if it is daylight savings time or not. It looks light it should work, but I am an embedded C programmer, not a php programmer. Am I missing something????

```
<?
$remove_hour = strtotime("Second Sunday March 0");  
$add_hour = strtotime("First Sunday November 0");   
$daylighttime  = time();    
if( $daylighttime >= $remove_hour && $daylighttime < $add_hour )  
{  
    $daylight_offset = 1;
}  
else  
{  
    $daylight_offset = 0; 
}
?>
```

Comment: Don't use strtotime for this. If you're going to work with dates and DST is a factor use `DateTime()`. It takes DST into account for you.

Comment: Like I said I am not a php programer, but I will look into it. Thanks

Comment: After more research it looks like this will fix my problems. Thanks